# use ajax call in new pop up window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, popup, window.open

I have an auto-complete textbox where user can insert an actor name and it works fine. There is a button "browse movies" which should populate a dynamic dropdown showing list of movies by the actor that user has inserted in the text-box. Also, there is another button "add to the list" that if user click on it, the selected options of this dropdown (movies) whould be added to another dropdown which shows all selected movies by user.

### Problem

I could populate dropdown dynamically when user clicked the button, also I could move the selected options to the new dropdown (selecteditems), but the problem is that I want to **show this dropdown in a new pop-up window** (not in the same page where user insert in the text-box). I really don't know how to do it.. should I make the ajax call in target.html (the new pop up window)? I appreciate if someone can let me know how I can do this.

This is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
           source: "actorsauto.php",
           minLength: 2,
           select: function (event, ui){
                    $("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function (){
                         var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
                 // Here goes your ajax call.      
                       $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                               console.log(response);
                               $("#movieName").html(response).show();
                        });
                    }).change();
             }
 });

$('#btnRight').on('click', function (e) {
         var selectedOpts = $('#movieName option:selected');
         if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
             alert("Nothing to move.");
             e.preventDefault();
         }

         $('#selectedItems').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
         $(selectedOpts).remove();
         $("#movieName").hide();
         $("#tags").val("");
        e.preventDefault();
 });

     function openWindow() { 
        window.open("target.html","_blank","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
     } 
  </script>

<html>
<body>
<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter an actor/actress name here" />
<input type=button onclick="javascript:openWindow()" value="Browse movies by this actor">
<select id="movieName" name="movieName[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style=display:none;>
<input type="button" value=">> Add to selected list >>" id="btnRight" style="display:none;" />
<select id="selectedItems" name="selectedItems[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px; size:10px;">
</select>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the results to show in a new browser window/tab or do you want to show a pop-up dialog within the same page?

Comment: @jwnace: I just don't want to populate dropdown in the same page because later I am going to hide this dropdown and I faced some space problems (I mean it caused a very bad look in the interface), so I decided to show it in a new window...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Sorry for any mistakes or if it's rubbish

**target.html**

```
// this goes in target.html
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: "actorsauto.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function () {
            var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
            // Here goes your ajax call.
            // here's some magic. using window.opener allows you 
            // to access variables and functions defined in the parent window.      
            window.opener.getMovies(selectedVal);
        }).change();
    }
});
```

**page.html**

```
// this stays in your parent window
function getMovies(value) {
    $.post("actions.php", { q: value}, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#movieName").html(response).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry if I am late, but could you please tell me where I have to call target.hmtl? also, I prefer the autocomplete remain in the main page and ONLY the dynamic dropdown should open in the new window (target,html)